# How to create FB-like action bar once and then use it in all the activities I need to

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to create an action bar almost like the one in Facebook app.
I am a bit confused, though, because all the materials I find about using action bars are very contradictory.

Some tutorials say extend ActionBarActivity, others are talking about menus with no mention of ActionBarActivity, third ones are talking about fragments?

I just need direction of what is the "right" way if there is one and I will learn the rest.

How is Facebook's action bar implemented?

I want to create a custom layout for it, and define what all buttons do and then just insert in in each activity I need.
Below it, I want to have custom tabs, and tabs should be different depending on each activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I depends on what you want to achieve. You have to use Fragments if you want to implement something like the chat in the facebook app which slides in from the side when tapping the symbol in the upper right corner. If you just want an actionbar with an overflow menu which you can tap to then choose different menu items (e.g. for opening another activity) you can simply use ActionBarActivity.

Comment: so if I get this right, If I want to make an action bar that is like facebook, I use the ActionBarActivity? But do I have to extend that class in every activity and implement everything so many times? How can I create it once and then just use it in every activity I need it?

Comment: Just use inheritance. Create one ActionBarActivity holding all the code which you need in every activity and make those activities inherit from that one so you don't have to duplicate your code.

Comment: ok will need a couple of days to implement this and will write back and prolly accept the answer

Comment: and this will not interfere with the drawer navigation on the left, right?

Comment: btw do I use the same method for the drawer?